# Need to do a custom search in excel

Tags: excel, filter

In one sheet I have a database of companies. But the problem is that there are some companies (row items) which I don't need. Now, in a separate sheet I have filled the first column with junk words and phrases. These junk words are keywords in the "Business Name" column in the database sheet.

So I want to filter the database sheet by the first column (Business Name) if one of the keywords in the junk column is present in the name.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a total answer, but in essence part of the solution. I think you may need to resort to something like a VBA macro/script for this. I did this in GoogleSheets. Excel works the same for [iferror](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) and [find](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/FIND-FINDB-functions-c7912941-af2a-4bdf-a553-d0d89b0a0628). If the cell D5 is 0 then you don't have a match. Any positive value would be something you'd want to include.
So presuming you could get this to work, you'd run a macro and in column B put a 0 if D5 was 0 otherwise place a 1. Then you could filter on column B for the '1' or just omit 0 and not bother to map 2,3,4 etc to 1.

Formulae
[image]
Result for A2 only
[image]
If that can be merged into a VBA script that spins thru each row and grabs column A you'd have your answer.

Comment: Thank for this @JGFMK. But I have no knowledge on how to use macros in excel. This is a one time thing I need. By any chance would you be able to guide me on how to write a macro for the same purpose.

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't done that stuff for many years. It's hindered by the fact I now use a Mac and Microsoft Office doesn't have as good a Visual Basic editor you used to get on Windows XP - the last time I used a Microsoft OS in earnest. I used to be able to access the Excel Object model and all it's properties via combo boxes (drop downs). Without this it would be like pulling teeth for me. If you are on a Windows machine you will  probably have more luck than me, with a non nobbled version of Excel. Try recording a macro and looking at the syntax. Also look for YouTube tutorials.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I found a workaround solution incase anyone in the future needs this. Please follow the link.https://superuser.com/questions/322455/excel-2007-filtering-out-rows-in-a-table-based-on-a-list